# Статическая переменная map. Использование как словарь

Tags: c++, qt

Использую статические открытые переменные типа QMap. Заполнение произвожу с помощью статической функции, которая возвращает QMap.

код:

```
// *.h
...
public:
    static QMap<uchar, QString> bDict;

private:
    static QMap<uchar, QString> createMapDictionaryB();
...
//////////////////////////////////////


// *.cpp
...
QMap<uchar, QString> ArrayNC::createMapDictionaryB()
{
    QMap<uchar, QString> map;
    map[1] = "Значение 1";
    map[3] = "Значение 2";
    map[4] = "Значение 3";
...
    return map;
}
```

При компиляции ошибки

> - ошибка: variable 'QMap bDict' has initializer but incomplete type
> - ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QMap'
> - ошибка: return type 'struct QMap' is incomplete

Comment: забыли `#include <QMap>` в хидере?

Comment: Попробуйте привести [mcve].

Comment: Действительно) Спасибо. 
Бывает)

Answer (score 2):

забыл #include  в хидере.
только и всего)

Answer (score 0):

Нет определения для bDict в .cpp файле.

```
QMap<uchar, QString> bDict ИМЯ_КЛАССА::bDict;
```

Comment: Не помогло.
ошибка: aggregate 'QMap<unsigned char, QString> ArrayNC::bDict' has incomplete type and cannot be defined